# Decimal Fields displays negative on windows from IBM AS400

Tags: sql, database, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have a scenario where I do a select with SQL on the Green screen from a table on the as400(DB2), and  I do the same SQL statement from a windows PC with a SQL tool.

On the as400(DB2) :
[image]

Notice the undrelined values 40229 and 41158. The Field type on the db2 side is DECIMAL  9.

Now When I run the same SQL on a windows PC using a Sql tool(IBM(R) Data Studio):

[image]

For some reason when the data gets returned as -40229 and -41158

It feels like an overflow of some sort but why and what?

When I navigate to the database structure from the Sql tool the field type is :

[image]

So on the as400 the fieldtype is DECIMAL 9 and from the Windows side its DECIMAL 9..

Why is this negative on Windows? Something to do with the type?

The SQL Windows : `select * from maxdtaclb.szciexp where TCNUOR ='129444'`

The SQL AS400: `select * from maxdtaclb/szciexp where TCNUOR ='129444'`

Did a select all where value is smaller than 0 and got results of 11 rows...

[image]

Again if I do a select on the green screen with the key of that same records it is negative???

Something I noticed is even if I use a rpgiv program to fetch the data from the table it is negative in the rpgiv program aswell..

Comment: I believe you can set formats for many things, including dates (you should probably change to use `*ISO`), in that tool.  I think it also includes numbers?  I'd check that first.  Might we see the statement?  Is it only this set of fields?  Is it only this row (and are we sure it's the same one, although that appears to be the case)?  Are you sure you're hitting the same table (haven't set `*LIBL` or something in the session)?

Comment: It is exactly the same table and same row being affected. The only thing that is weird is that if I select another row the value is correct(not negative) ,its like just some off them are incorrect like in my example. I will check the *ISO formats..

Comment: Example of the a correct one check my first image of the as400 the value :  18919 displays correct on the windows side but 40229 displays negative... and thats why I think something like an overflow?

Comment: I'm with @Clockwork-Muse...are you positive it's the same row?  Try adding `RRN()` to your select like so: `select rrn(a), a.* from maxdtaclb.szciexp A where TCNUOR ='129444'`

Comment: If it was overflow, it would be highly unlikely to be the same value other than negative. Also, packed decimal doesn't overflow like integers do.

Comment: Those damn packed fields.

Comment: @Charles I ran the Row number sql and Its the same row... so I am 100% sure.

Comment: @Charles I changed the SQL to select all where the value is smaller than 0.. and I got results of 11 rows in the whole table. See updated post.

Comment: I also noticed when accessing or fetching the data from the table using a RPGIV function I also get a negative? even more weird....

Comment: I checked in all 11 instances that every time the value is correct but it is just negative...

Comment: @Renier See my revised answer for a suggested solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file was created from a DDS source member (rather than an SQL DDL `CREATE TABLE` statement), it may be possible that the field was defined using the `EDTCDE` keyword.  Edit codes can be used to control how numeric values are displayed in query output in an interactive session.  Using an edit code of 1, 2, 3, or 4 will cause negative signs to be suppressed.  If you use the field in an expression, SQL will generate a derived column that is no longer formatted by the edit code.

Example file definition in DDS source member::

```
            R RDMC001P                           
              NUMFLD1        5P 0       EDTCDE(3)
```

Example SQL session:

```
> insert into dmclib/dmc001p           
  values (-12345)                      
  1 rows inserted in DMC001P in DMCLIB.
> select NUMFLD1 from dmclib/dmc001p         
  NUMFLD1
   12345
> select decimal(numfld1,5,0) as NUMFLD2 from dmclib/dmc001p       
  NUMFLD2 
   12,345-
```

[Here's a link](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzakc/rzakcmstdfedtcd.htm) to the 7.2 IBM manual describing the codes available for the EDTCDE DDS keyword.  (It applies to physical files even though the title mentions display files.)

Comment: Dang..forgot all about edit codes.  Another option is the source isn't available is to use the `Display File Field Description - (DSPFFD)` command

Comment: Wow I checked it using DSPFFD and Guess  what.. Both the fields are defined as Edit Code 4 witch means if the value is actually negative, Then don't display the sign. Thanks allot! Learn new things every day. Why would one use this edit code to create a table? If the value is negative surely you would want to know?

Comment: Argh.  I went looking for this in regards to _display files_ (but couldn't remember what it was called - I've been out too long) before noticing it was one of the standard tools.  Shoulda kept looking...

Comment: You'd use one of the sign suppressing edit codes when you don't expect to ever have a negative.  When placing the field on a 5250 screen or a report, it will take up once less character.

Answer (score 0):

What tool are you using to look at the results from the green screen?  I'm assuming STRSQL.

Given that 2 out of 3 tools (Data Studio / RPG) show the value as negative, I'd say the value is negative.

One thing to try, use the HEX() function to see the hex value of the data.  You should see either '000040229D' for a negative value or '000040229F' if positive.

However, '000040229B' is an valid though little used alternative for a negative. It's possible the green screen tool you're using isn't recognizing it.

But, at least on my system (v7.1 TR 9) STRSQL at least displays both versions of the negative value properly with the negative sign.
[image]